# NodeJS - MongoDB: use an opening connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

It is better to open a new connection or re-use ? when using module, because I'm used to separate my code into several files.

a.js

```
module.exports = function (req, res) {

  new mongodb.... (err, db) { // open a connection
    b(function (err, result) {
      db.close(); // close the connection
      res.send(result);
    });
  });

};
```

b.js

```
// re-open a connection ? or take the connection of "a.js" ? (passing "db")
```

> When asynchronous, one must be careful to continue using the same connection (socket). This ensures that the next operation will not begin until after the write completes.

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you `require('somemodule')` and then require it again a second time, it will use the ALREADY loaded instance. This lets you create singletons quite easily.

So - inside of `sharedmongo.js`:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');

// this variable will be used to hold the singleton connection
var mongoCollection = null;

var getMongoConnection = function(readyCallback) {

  if (mongoCollection) {
    readyCallback(null, mongoCollection);
    return;
  }

  // get the connection
  var server = new mongo.Server('127.0.0.1', 27017, {
    auto_reconnect: true
  });

  // get a handle on the database
  var db = new mongo.Db('squares', server);
  db.open(function(error, databaseConnection) {
    databaseConnection.createCollection('testCollection', function(error, collection) {

      if (!error) {
        mongoCollection = collection;
      }

      // now we have a connection
      if (readyCallback) readyCallback(error, mongoCollection);
    });
  });
};
module.exports = getMongoConnection;
```

Then inside of `a.js`:

```
var getMongoConnection = require('./sharedmongo.js');
var b = require('./b.js');
module.exports = function (req, res) {
  getMongoConnection(function(error, connection){
    // you can use the Mongo connection inside of a here
    // pass control to b - you don't need to pass the mongo
    b(req, res);
  })
}
```

And inside of `b.js`:

```
var getMongoConnection = require('./sharedmongo.js');
module.exports = function (req, res) {
  getMongoConnection(function(error, connection){
    // do something else here
  })
}
```

The idea is when both `a.js` and `b.js` call `getMongoCollection`, the first time it will connect, and the second time it will return the already connected one. This way it ensure you are using the same connection (socket).

Comment: but why it is better than pass the "db" variable ? and close in the callback ? (for my case)

Comment: Because in your example every hit on a web page will close the mongo connection and then re-open it for the next hit - if you are getting 2000 hits a second then this will add a lot more work (like several times slower)...  The idea is to have the new mongodb.... (err, db) OUTSIDE of the  function (req, res) { so it does not have to reconnect for every web-page...

Comment: Great job ! thanks! but, so, we have a single connection? It is dangerous ..?

Comment: Do you mean dangerous in case the connection goes away - you can listen for close events and rebuild it in such case...  If you mean - there is only one database connection is it slow - node.js works on a single process etc etc so it won't be slow

Comment: Okok... I have not tested to have proof. But I believe you. So I will do like this. Thank you again.

Comment: Hey, and for redis ? please, (for a chat using socketio for exemple) i should open one per client? one per script ? or one for all ? Thanks !

Comment: Ohh, i would like to have more accurate about "dangerous": if the connection goes away. How do? (i store my collections in an object like your above example) Thnak you man :)

Comment: Hey man - with Redis you can copy the same idea - in sharedredis.js you would have getRedisConnection which returns and allocates to the cache... To detect disconnects - you could add:

db.on('close', function(){
// code to rebuild the connection here
})

I'll leave how you plug this in up to you : )

Comment: Ok thank you, you think it is the best solution ? Because I don't want to re-change ...

Comment: I can't say it's the 'best' solution but it allows me to use a single database connection from within a single process with no problems thus far - I would encourage you to plug in into your code and understand it though and therefore you will know it's the best solution : )

Comment: Hey man - just answered a similar question - there is a better version of the library above : )

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037655/node-js-mongodb-native-driver-connection-sharing/12039606#12039606

Comment: I don't know why she's better.. ? More, you declare `var mongoDatabases = {};` in the function .. wtf ? thank you man ;)

Comment: It's better because it wraps it all up nicely - the mongoDatabases is inside the function because it's a 'closure' - welcome to the world of functional programming : ) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science) - put bracket onto the end of the link

Comment: It works but I would tend to declare `mongoDatabases` out of the function. Here, you store collection. In the other version, you store just the database.. so I think I should combine v1 with v2 ?

Comment: But yes, in your second example, you have a more compact structure (I don't know if this is the right term) declaring all into the function

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15585/discussion-between-cydgy-and-bino-carlos)

Comment: I don't know if you have notification for the chat, for answer :) - maybe you prefere discuss here ?