# Node.js Mongodb-native driver connection sharing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

***main.js***

```
var http = require('http');
var UserModel = require('./models/user.js');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
  UserModel.create({
  }), function(e, o){
    if(e) { console.log(e); } else {
    } console.log(o); }
  });
}).listen(3000);
```

***connections.js***

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');

module.exports = {
    dbMain: new mongo.Db('main', new mongo.Server('127.0.0.1', 27017, { auto_reconnect: true }, {})),
    dbLog: new mongo.Db('log', new mongo.Server('127.0.0.1', 27017, { auto_reconnect: true }, {}))
};
```

***/models/user.js***

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var db = require('./connections.js').dbMain;

module.exports = {
  create: function(newData, callback){
    db.open(function(e, db){
      db.collection('users', function(e, collection){
        collection.insert(newData, callback);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

When I use the code above, the server crashes with the problem that, the SECOND time a request comes in, we still have the database connection opened, so lets add db.close to our Users.create function.

```
  create: function(newData, callback){
    db.open(function(e, db){
      db.collection('users', function(e, collection){
        collection.insert(newData, function(e, o){
          db.close(); // Voila.
          callback(e, o);
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

At this stage the server CAN still crash, because of multiple connections open, I don't understand why or how this can happen but it does.

How do I organize my project into models (I don't want to use Mongoose, my validation is done in a different layer not the model, so Mongoose would be an overkill for me)? Also how do I handle connections in the project?

Comment: put `db.open()` in `connection.js` and export the already opened db objects. See https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/node-mongodb-native/msgPpoQs2iQ%5B1-25%5D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you could have a library that wraps all this up nicely - it means that only one connection to the database will be opened and the same (open) connection will be returned for the second request - if you are getting 1000+ per second, this is a make-or-break issue (i.e. not re-opening the connection each request)...

**users.js**:

```
var connections = require('./connections.js');

var serverCache = connections('127.0.0.1', 27017); 

module.exports = {
  create: function(newData, callback){
    serverCache('main', 'users', function(e, collection){
      collection.insert(newData, callback);
    })
  }
}
```

**connections.js**

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');

// a mongo connection cache
// pass in host & port
// it returns a function accepting dbName, collectionName & callback
var mongoCache = function(host, port){

  // keep our open connections
  var mongoDatabases = {};

  var ensureDatabase = function(dbName, readyCallback){
    // check if we already have this db connection open
    if(mongoDatabases[dbName]){
      readyCallback(null, mongoDatabases[dbName]);
      return;
    }

    // get the connection
    var server = new mongo.Server(host, port, {auto_reconnect: true});

    // get a handle on the database
    var db = new mongo.Db(dbName, server);
    db.open(function(error, databaseConnection){
      if(error) throw error;

      // add the database to the cache
      mongoDatabases[dbName] = databaseConnection;

      // remove the database from the cache if it closes
      databaseConnection.on('close', function(){
        delete(mongoDatabases[dbName]);
      })

      // return the database connection
      readyCallback(error, databaseConnection);
    })
  }

  var ensureCollection = function(dbName, collectionName, readyCallback){

    ensureDatabase(dbName, function(error, databaseConnection){
      if(error) throw error;

      databaseConnection.createCollection(collectionName, function(error, collection) {
        if(error) throw error;

        // return the collection finally
        readyCallback(error, collection);
      })

    })
  }

  return ensureCollection;
}

module.exports = mongoCache;
```

Comment: good point - I'm sure you can expand the general idea though :)

Comment: true, but I still don't understand, why would we just not open / close all connections, and is this concept the same as pooling?

Comment: This is not pooling - it is the caching of an open connection to avoid having to re-open it each time...

Pooling is where you manage multiple connections and pick one to use each time - you could easily extend this cache into a pooling library by managing multiple connections (equally true for something to manage replica sets)...

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently using a global connection with multiple http requests. In the past I created a complex library that was creating several connections to MongoDB and picking up one randomly for each connection.

Later I found that the native driver can do that for me, which is pretty neat. Currently I'm using a single object, and the driver chooses to which connection send the query.

```
var srvOpts = {
    auto_reconnect: true,
    poolSize: 10,
};

var conn = new Mongo.Server("localhost", 27017, srvOpts),
    db = new Mongo.Db("dbname", conn, {});

db.open(function (){});
```

As you can this is a great idea, I'm thinking to copy that idea into the Redis driver that I'm using, but I'm short on time so I doubt that I will do any time soon.