# Behavior of require in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I currently have a database connection module containing the following:

```
var mongodb = require("mongodb");
var client = mongodb.MongoClient;
client.connect('mongodb://host:port/dbname', { auto_reconnect: true },
      function(err, db) {
         if (err) {
            console.log(err);
         } else {
            // export db as member of exports
            module.exports.db = db;
         }
      }
);
```

I can then successfully access it doing the following:

**users.js**

```
var dbConnection = require("./db.js");
var users = dbConnection.db.collection("users");
users.find({name: 'Aaron'}).toArray(function(err, result) {
  // do something
});
```

However, if I instead export `module.exports = db`, i.e., try to assign the `exports` object to the `db` object instead of  making it a member of exports, and try to access it in `users.js` via `var db = require("./db.js");` the object is undefined, why?

If it is because there is a delay in setting up the connection (shouldn't `require()` wait until the module finishes running its code before assigning the value of module.exports?), then why do neither of these examples work?

**one.js**

```
setTimeout(function() {
   module.exports.x = {test: 'value'};
}, 500);
```

**two.js**

```
var x = require("./one");
console.log(x.test);
```

OR

**one.js**

```
setTimeout(function() {
   module.exports.x = {test: 'value'};
}, 500);
```

**two.js**

```
setTimeout(function() {
   var x = require("./one");
   console.log(x.test);
}, 1000);
```

Running `$ node two.js` prints `undefined` in both cases instead of `value`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 key points to understand here and then I will explain them in detail.

1. module.exports is an object and objects are passed by copy-of-reference in JavaScript.
2. require is a **synchronous** function.
3. client.connect is an **asynchronous** function.

As you suggested, it is a timing thing.  node.js cannot know that module.exports is going to change later.  That's not it's problem.  How would it know that?

When `require` runs, it finds a file that meets its requirements based on the path you entered, reads it and executes it, and caches module.exports so that other modules can `require` the same module and not have to re-initialize it (which would mess up variable scoping, etc.)

client.connect is an asynchronous function call, so after you execute it, the module finishes execution and the `require` call stores a copy of the module.exports reference and returns it to users.js.  Then you set `module.exports = db`, but it's too late.  You are replacing the module.exports reference with a reference to db, but the module export in the node `require` cache is pointing to the old object.

It's better to define module.exports as a function which will get a connection and then pass it to a callback function like so:

```
var mongodb = require("mongodb");
var client = mongodb.MongoClient;

module.exports = function (callback) {
    client.connect('mongodb://host:port/dbname', { auto_reconnect: true },
          function(err, db) {
             if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                callback(err);
             } else {
                // export db as member of exports
                callback(err, db);
             }
          }
    )
};
```

Warning: though it's outside the scope of this answer, be very careful with the above code to make sure you close/return the connections appropriately, otherwise you will leak connections.

Comment: Why does setting `module.exports.db = db` work though? Wouldn't the same thing be happening whether I set it to `module.exports` or `module.exports.db`?

Comment: It's different because module.exports is a reference to an object and you are not changing it to refer to a different object.  Rather, you are mutating the existing object.

Answer (score 1):

> shouldn't `require() wait until the module finishes running its code
>   before assigning the value of module.exports?

`module.exports.db` is setting in callback, this operation is async, so in `user.js` you can't get `db.collection`.
It will be better to [add](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html#mongoclient-connect) collections in `connect` callback.

You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11993907/2525067) answer to change you code and use `shared connection` in other modules.

Comment: I CAN get it in `user.js` if I set it to `module.exports.db`, it is only a problem if I try to set it to just `module.exports`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `dbConnection.db` is undefined because the connection is made asynchronously which means by definition the node code just continues to execute without waiting for the DB connection to  be established.

> shouldn't require() wait until the module finishes running its code before assigning the value of module.exports?

Nope, it just doesn't work that way. `require` is for code that is always there. Database connections aren't code and aren't always there. Best not to confuse these two types of resources and how to reference them from you program.

Comment: I would be interested to know what the distinction between setting `module.exports` and `module.exports.db`, because the latter works fine for me despite the delay. I understand the reason why the former is not working but don't understand why `module.exports.db` is not subject to the same fate.

Answer (score 0):

And what is the question? This is how `require` works - it gets the module synchronously and pass you the exports.

You suggestion to 'wait until code is run' could be answered two ways:

1. It waits until the code is run. The `setTimeout` has successfully finished. Learn to separate asynchronous callbacks aimed for future from the actual thread.
2. If you mean "until all of the asynchronous callbacks are run", that's nonsense - what if some of them is not run at all, because it wait for, I don't know, mouse click, but user does not have mouse attached? (and how do you even define 'all code has run?' That every statement was run at least once? What about `if (true) { thisruns(); } else { thiswontrunever(); }`?)